# How to handle selected-index change event of a drop down in MVC4 Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following control in my view page. How can I handle the selected change event in a very simple way?

```
@{
            List<SelectListItem> invoiceTypes= new List<SelectListItem>();
            invoiceTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "--Select One--",
                Value = "",
                Selected = true
            });
            invoiceTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Form 8",
                Value = "Form 8"
            });
            invoiceTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Form 8B",
                Value = "Form 8B"
            });
            invoiceTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "eBay",
                Value = "eBay"
            });
            invoiceTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Snapdeal",
                Value = "Snapdeal"
            });
            }

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InvoiceType, invoiceTypes, new { @class = "dropdownlist"})
```

Comment: Use change event of select

Comment: it should work like normal dropdown so, $('.dropdownlist').change(function(){//code here})

Comment: Thanks! Also I want to pass the selected item value to an action method. So how to call controller action from inside the jquery?

Answer (score 1):

`Html.DropDownListFor` will be render as `select` like

```
<select class="dropdownlist">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="eBay">eBay</option>
    <option value="Snapdeal">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
```

You can handle `change` event like

```
 $(".dropdownlist").change(function () {
     alert(this.value);
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/958N8/)

Comment: Thanks! Also I want to pass the selected item value to an action method. So how to call controller action inside the jquery?

Comment: @Jobi, Can you post where you want to use the selected value?

Comment: For example, inside the "Update" action method of "InvoiceController" class. Based on the selected item, I want do some processing..

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dropdownlist").change(function () {
        var item = this.value;
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
        $.post("/Invoice/Update", { Item: item });
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use  OnChange Event of Jquery since its same as normal HTML Control:


   $(.dropdownlist).change(function()
{

  // Write your code here..
}

);
```

Hope this helps..